How to restrict the US amount Regex pattern currency input field from accepting alphabets angular
I have the below RegEx wherein the amount entered by user is transformed into US currency format. The amount is getting transformed into US currency without any issues. But  the input also accepts alphabets(which is actually not visible on screen) , so when i try to angular binding, the alphabets are visible.
I have a solution where i can use keydown event and restrict alphabets using keyCode, but I dont want to create a separate function instead I want to modify the same Regex.
How can i modify the same regex so that alphabets are also restricted. Any help is much appreciated.
<input type="text" (input)="validateInput($event)" (blur)="transformAmount($event)">

transformAmount(event:any){
this.form.controls[getFormControlName].setValue(this.currencyPipe.transform((this.form.controls[getFormControlName].value.replace(/\$+/g,'').replace(/,/g,''))));
}

validateInput(event:any) {
event.target.value=
event.target.value.replace
(/[^0-9.]/g,'').replace(/^\.$/g,'').replace(/(\..*?)\..*/g,'$1'.replace(/(\.\d{2}).+/g,'$1')
}


You can try the following way. Here I added a formControl and also changed the validateInput() and transformAmount a little bit.
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CurrencyPipe } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-currency-input',
  template: `
    <input type="text" 
           [formControl]="amountControl"
           (input)="validateInput($event)" 
           (blur)="transformAmount()">
  `,
  providers: [CurrencyPipe]
})
export class CurrencyInputComponent {
  amountControl: FormControl;

  constructor(private currencyPipe: CurrencyPipe) {
    this.amountControl = new FormControl('');
  }

  validateInput(event: any) {
    const input = event.target.value;
    const sanitizedInput = input.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '')
                                .replace(/^\./, '')
                                .replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1')
                                .replace(/(\.\d{2}).*/g, '$1');
    
    event.target.value = sanitizedInput;
    this.amountControl.setValue(sanitizedInput, {emitEvent: false});
  }

  transformAmount() {
    const rawValue = this.amountControl.value.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');
    const transformedValue = this.currencyPipe.transform(rawValue, 'USD', 'symbol', '1.2-2');
    this.amountControl.setValue(transformedValue, {emitEvent: false});
  }
}

The regex explanations are these:

replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ''): This removes any character that is not a
digit or a period, effectively restricting alphabets and other
special characters.
replace(/^./, ''): This removes a leading period if it exists.
replace(/(..*)./g, '$1'): This ensures only one period exists in the input.
replace(/(.\d{2}).*/g, '$1'): This limits the input to two decimal places.

